# I have a problem in using the fancybox plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am following the guide here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/

Please scroll down to "inline" and read the info part about making the box scrollable and then try the codepen example there. In that example there is an open demo button. If you click on it then a pop up box opens and inside that box there is a toggle content button. If you click that button then the text shows and it is scrollable.

I need to remove the toggle content button and directly show the scrollable text. At the bottom of the text I need to put some links.

https://codepen.io/shadi-shtaklef/pen/oaayMQ is my codepen example. It is the exact same as the original example. I just removed the toggle content button and I added

```
Email: <a href="mailto:info@mdscomputers.ae">info@mdscomputers.ae</a><br>
Website: <a href="http://www.mdscomputers.ae" target="_blank">www.mdscomputers.ae</a>
```

At the bottom of the text, the problem is that when I click on the open demo button the scrollable text is automatically scrolling down to the bottom to those 2 links. How do I disable that?

You can do the same edits in the original codepen example and the same thing will happen.

Comment: Does this happen only in code pen?  it does seem odd that if there any link at the bottom, it auto scrolls to that link.  Maybe that's a *hidden feature* of fancy box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation, it automatically focus on the first focusable element after opening modal. And in your modal's content

```
<a href="mailto:info@mdscomputers.ae">info@mdscomputers.ae</a>
```

is a first focusable element. That's why modal is automatically scrolling down.

If you want to change this default behaviour then you can use a data attribute

```
data-auto-focus="false"
```

in **Open Demo** anchor.

See the Pen [fancybox v3.5 - Scrollable content](https://codepen.io/nirajkaushal/pen/KGGxPG/) by Niraj Kaushal ([@nirajkaushal](https://codepen.io/nirajkaushal)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: excellent :))))))))) thanks very much. it worked. one more question. in the modal box that opens i can only scroll down by clicking the mouse in the scroll bar and pressing the down key doesnt work. can i make it scroll down by using the down key?

Comment: My pleasure :) please accept my answer if you think this is right solution for your problem. for more configuration see this http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution for this set `tabindex:0` to modal as shown below:

```
<div id="modal" tabindex="0">
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/vikasjadhav/pen/OBBwex)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hacky but it works; https://codepen.io/mcourto/pen/yRRqEq

I used jquery (as you are using it already) `$( "#button" ).click();` to click the button and hide it using css
I have then set the tab index of the text area to 1 so it scroll to the top by default.